# Building debs for FreeRadius 3.0.15

Tags: debian, packaging

After a [security warning about FreeRadius](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-9148), I am trying to build the FreeRadius 3.0.15 installation .deb files for Debian 9/Stretch for placing in my local repository.

I actually also need that version for a RadSec project and a couple of other bug fixes.

I build them using the following instructions:

```
git clone https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server.git
cd freeradius-server
git fetch origin v3.0.x:v3.0.x
git checkout v3.0.x
fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc
```

However, when compiling it, I got back the following error:

```
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source package freeradius
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source version 3.0.15+git
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source distribution unstable
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source changed by Alan DeKok <aland@freeradius.org>
dpkg-buildpackage: info: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source --before-build freeradius-server
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: error: Unmet build dependencies: libjson0 | libjson-c2
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libjson-c2` does not exist in Debian 9; doing an:

```
$apt-cache search libjson-c
libjson-c3 - JSON manipulation library - shared library
```

It is fairly evident it is now called `libjson-c3`; so I replaced in the debian `control` file of the project at `freeradius-server/debian/control` at line 10, `libjson-c2` for `libjson-c3`

```
 10  libjson0 | libjson-c3,
```

Doing again :

```
fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc
```

It compiles with success, and produces at the directory at `freeradius-server/..` the following files:

`freeradius_3.0.15+git_amd64.deb
freeradius-common_3.0.15+git_all.deb
freeradius-config_3.0.15+git_amd64.deb
freeradius-dbg_3.0.15+git_amd64.deb
freeradius-dhcp_3.0.15+git_amd64.deb
freeradius-iodbc_3.0.15+git_amd64.deb
freeradius-krb5_3.0.15+git_amd64.deb
freeradius-ldap_3.0.15+git_amd64.deb
freeradius-memcached_3.0.15+git_amd64.deb
freeradius-mysql_3.0.15+git_amd64.deb
freeradius-postgresql_3.0.15+git_amd64.deb
freeradius-redis_3.0.15+git_amd64.deb
freeradius-rest_3.0.15+git_amd64.deb
freeradius-utils_3.0.15+git_amd64.deb
freeradius-yubikey_3.0.15+git_amd64.deb
libfreeradius3_3.0.15+git_amd64.deb
libfreeradius-dev_3.0.15+git_amd64.deb`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you only need to upgrade FreeRadius to fix the vulnerability in question, you can install the latest FreeRadius packages from unstable; they [fix the vulnerability](https://tracker.debian.org/news/846538) too (with a minimal patch to 3.0.12).

An interesting general solution to this kind of problem, for users running testing and wishing to install security fixes from unstable as soon as they’re available, is to use [Paul Wise’s extension to `debsecan`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=725934) — it automatically pins packages to their unstable version as necessary when security fixes are released there.

Comment: Thanks for your input Stephen; I actually need more recent packages than 3.0.12 for a RadSec project and a couple of other bug fixes. I also do not feel entirely  confy drinking from unstable in production systems due to bad experiences in the past.

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth mentioning the extra requirements in your question ;-). You seem to be running testing in production; full security support with such a setup does involve pulling in from unstable from time to time (or rebuilding as you’re doing). Of course once Debian 9 is released you’ll be able to just use stable security! I note in passing (for othe readers) that upgrading to 3.0.15 means you need to provide your own security support going forwards.

Comment: All valid points; I have actually moved forward in some systems to Debian 9 to get support for newer packages, and not for duplicating upgrade work as the launching date is already quite near; I have been drinking from the FR git for years now, as often both the official stable tar.gz and the Debian packages are barely adequate for our needs.